# Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "percentage"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

vue show me this problem , i dont know what happend

my el progress

```
<el-progress :percentage="percentCompleted" v-show="uploadingVideo"></el-progress>
```

```
data() {
return{
      percentCompleted: 0,
}
}
```

my function

```
onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
          this.percentCompleted = Math.round(
            (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
          );
          this.$forceUpdate();
        }.bind(this)
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an object in data hook:

```
data() {
    return {
         percentCompleted: 0,
    }
}
```

Other than that could be a problem in your `<el-progress>` component.

Comment: i return an object in data hook but the same problem

Comment: could be possible that you're mutating the "percentage" prop directly in your el-progress component ?

Answer (score 0):

In your  el-progress component you might be updating the value of the percentage prop. If you are then you need to create a local variable and update that instead. Then you emit that value back out of your component. Then you set the parent component to listen for that event.

If the component is just a functional one then maybe something wrong with that function you provided like why are you doing forceupdate is it needed.